# in clojure why isn't x identified if defined as [x] argument and then referenced as x? in code block?

Tags: clojure, lisp

```
(defn boolean [x]
  (if (x? nil or false)
    (false)
    (true)))
```

I get

> Unable to resolve symbol: x? in this context

`x` is an argument to the function and I just reference it, what did I miss?

Comment: why do you expect `x` to be `x?`? And `(x? nil or false)` is not valid syntax

Comment: Note that both `false` and `nil` are considered `false` in Clojure. Everything else is considered a `true` value. You don't need to cast it to use it as a boolean so your function might be redundant. eg. `(or nil false 12) ; => 12 (a true value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your problem (you didn't ever defined `x?`) but you could implement it in Clojure like this

```
(defn boolean [x]
  (not
    (or 
      (nil? x) 
      (false? x))))

(boolean 1)
#=> true
(boolean nil)
#=> false
(boolean false)
#=> false
(boolean [])
#=> true
```

Or more implicit solution

```
(defn boolean [x]
  (if x
    true
    false))
```

Or your approach:

```
(defn boolean [x]
  (if (or (nil? x) (false? x))
    false
    true))
```

Answer (score 3):

Because x and x? are two different names. Your function could be simply written as

```
(defn boolean [x]
  (if x true false))
```

Answer (score 2):

In clojure `x?` is the name of a symbol, not a symbol `x` and an operator `?`. The compiler is telling you that you didn't define any variable or binding named `x?`.

In addition `(false)` and `(true)` call the boolean values as a function. That will throw a run time error. Use `false` and `true` instead.